# Constructing hitting sets for randomized algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms

Suppose A($\cdot$,$\cdot$) is an efficient randomized algorithm and L is a language such that

$\text{If }x \in L, \text{Pr}_r[(A(x,r) = 1)] = 1$ and if $x \notin L, \text{Pr}_r[A(x, r) = 0] \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Let $H$ be a hitting set such that for all inputs $x$ of length $n$, if $x \notin L$, then $\exists y \in H, A(x, y) = 0$.

We need to show that there exists a hitting set $H$ of size $O(n)$.

My idea is that from the condition $x \notin L, \text{Pr}_r[A(x, r) = 0] \ge \frac{1}{2}$, we can get that $x \notin L, \text{Pr}_r[A(x, r) = 1] < \frac{1}{2}$. Then we can randomly choose $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_m$ to construct a set $S$. Then for any input $x \notin L, \Pi_{i = 1}^{i = m}Pr[A(x, y_i) = 1] < 2^{-m}$. Therefore, the probability that there exists at least one $y_i$ such that $A(x, y_i) = 0$ is $1 - 2^{-m}$. Now the problem is if we need to prove the hitting set $H$ must exist, then $1 - 2^{-m}$ should be 1, which means $m$ should be large enough. However, I cannot find the relationship between $m$ and $n$ and how come if $m$ in size of $O(n)$ would prove such $y_i$ must exist.

Or maybe I am going in the wrong way. Can somebody help me with this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the distribution for $r$ when you say $\mathrm{Pr}_r$? Note there is no uniform distribution over the set of all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ consists of $m$ seeds chosen uniformly at random (thus $|H|$ could be smaller than $m$). For each $x \notin L$, the probability that $A(x,r) = 1$ for all $r \in H$ is at most $2^{-m}$. Since there are at most $2^n$ inputs of length $n$ not in $L$, we get that the probability that $H$ is not a hitting set is at most $2^n/2^m$. Choosing $m = n+1$, we see that the probability that $H$ is not a hitting set is at most $1/2$, and in particular there must exist a hitting set of size at most $n+1$. If $L \cap \Sigma^n \neq \emptyset$, we can improve this to $m = n$.

Comment: Thanks for your replying! It is really helpful.